# how to compare two dates in C# Without comparing the time?

Tags: asp.net, date, compare

I want to compare two dates in C# i have tried Toshortdate() but its not working for me i dont know why? I just want to compare the dates not the time.. My code is as below:

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(b.CreatedDate).ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(objbreedable.LastBDate).ToShortDateString()
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Date property.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(b.CreatedDate).Date == Convert.ToDateTime(objbreedable.LastBDate).Date
```